# What is identity arrow in the category Set?

Tags: category-theory

Given is category *Set* Given two objects from this category, $A$, and $B$, which are sets without any other structure, there is an arrow $f: A \to B$, from $A$ to $B$, which is any total function from $A$ to $B$.

For given set $A$, there is ( by axiom of CT ) identity arrow $1_A$ .

Then it looks like identity arrow may be a permutation...

Buy identity arrow for a given object has to be unique. And there is many permutations for given set $A$.

**So do we have here "equivalence class" of identity arrow?**

Comment: It may be useful to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21951/the-identity-morphism-in-mathbfset-is-the-identity-function?rq=1

Comment: OK, thank You - I understand now.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the identity arrow must obey certain rules (per definition of category):
For any $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$ we have $f\circ 1_A=f$ and $1_A\circ g=g$. By choosing suitable $B,f,g$ as objects and morphisms (here: sets and maps) you can veriy that $1_A$ for any object $A$ of the category of sets **must** be the identity map $A\to A$, $x\mapsto x$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity arrow $1_A \in \text{Hom}(A,A)$ is precisely the identity permutation $a \mapsto a$. This is the case in any concrete category, such as groups, modules, topological spaces, etc.